# SSIS audit step encountering errors

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a step in my SSIS package where I'd like to update the latest row in my execution log (T1) with information from the latest row in another table (T2).

I get an error around the 'Where' statement

```
UPDATE T1
SET 
    [Survey_Size] = ssd.[FileName]
    ,Survey_Start_Date = ssd.[Start_Date]
    ,Survey_End_Date = ssd.[End_Date]
    ,[EndTime] = getdate()
    ,loaded = 1
FROM (SELECT max(log_sk) AS maxSk FROM T1) A
JOIN (SELECT max(PK) AS maxPK FROM T2) SS 
JOIN (SELECT PK, [FileName], Start_Date, End_Date, Survey_Size FROM T2) ssd ON ss.maxPK = ssd.pk
WHERE log_sk = a.maxSk
```

Table 1 looks like this:

```
log_sk | FileName | Survey_Size | Start_Date | End_Date
```

and I'd like to update the information from Table 2 which looks like below, where FileName would be a joining key in both

```
PK | FileName | Start_Date | End_Date | Survey_Size
```

Comment: Could you provide the full error message? Also: Does the statement work inside of SSMS? Looks strange with the T1 alias being in a subquery.

Comment: It does not work in SSMS- I know something is off but not sure what

Comment: The JOIN for the SS alias doesn't have an ON condition.  That's probably what is it complaining about.   Change that JOIN to a "CROSS JOIN"

Comment: Thanks @TimMylott. The Cross join worked perfectly!

Comment: @MZEN; Please mark the answer if it was helpful or comment it if-else.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite it with CTE Because it's more efficient and much more readable.

```
;With LastT1 as (
    Select
        log_sk as ID,
        Survey_Size,
        Survey_Start_Date,
        Survey_End_Date,
        EndTime,
        loaded,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by log_sk Desc) as Row_No
    From T1
), LatestT2 as (
    Select
        PK as ID,
        [FileName],
        [Start_Date],
        End_Date,
        Survey_Size,
        ROW_NUMBER() over (order by PK Desc) as Row_No
    From T2
)
Update Source
Set
    Source.[Survey_Size] = LatestT2.[FileName],
    Source.Survey_Start_Date = LatestT2.[Start_Date],
    Source.Survey_End_Date = LatestT2.[End_Date],
    Source.[EndTime] = getdate(),
    Source.loaded = 1
From LastT1 as Source
Inner Join LatestT2 on Source.ID = LatestT2.ID and LatestT2.Row_No = 1
Where Source.Row_No = 1
```